# How to prompt user to auth API access after revoking it on the service side in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

We're working on a connector for Google Data Studio. It required authenticating with our API, however I am wondering how to prompt the user to re-auth with our API if they revoke OAuth access from our service side of things, not the Data Studio side.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what [resetAuth()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#resetauth) is for. `resetAuth()` is called when a connector is revoked through the /datasources/create/ ui.

Comment: Yeah, I gave that a try, and we just added a nice detailed error message for this case, that explains how the user can go edit the connection of the connector to re-auth.

Comment: that is properly the best way given the circumstances. I did a similar thing for my users.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved. resetAuth is now called when a connector is revoked through the /datasources/create/ ui. Could you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Sorry @diminishedprime, I overlooked the notification about your comment. Better late than never, I updated my answer.